# update to matplotlib prepends 'alt' to keyrelease event.key

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib

I updated matplotlib from v1.1 to v1.2.0 win32.  I use mpl_connect to handle keyevents.  Where I used to check keyrelease event.key for e.g. 'q' or 'escape', now all keys are 'alt+q', 'alt+escape'.  Any idea why ?

Example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def close_fig(event):
   print event.key
   if event.key == 'q':
      plt.close(event.canvas.figure)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_release_event', close_fig)

data = [0,10,11,12]
ax.plot(data)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is most strange.  Can you post a quick minimal example?

Comment: it works as expected on a linux box...

Comment: I have the exact same problem, Python 3.3 + Matplotlib 1.2.0 w32 + numpy 1.7.0rc1 w32, on a w7 x64 system and on a Win XP system. MaX.

Comment: same here.  Win7 Python 2.7.3 32bit, matplotlib-1.2.1-py2.7 numpy-1.7.0-py2.7-win32

Comment: same problem for me.. using win8 64 bit python3.3 but with key_press_event

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug in the modifier key logic added to matplotlib v1.2.
Please report this example to the matplotlib issue tracker https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/new with the above example and the details relevant discussed in http://matplotlib.org/faq/troubleshooting_faq.html#getting-help . In particular, this is going to be very likely a backend problem, so please provide the backend you are using along with OS information.

Thanks!